# SPI Clock and CS signals

Tags: spi

I have one doubt regarding SPI. I am very new to this module. I know that communication is initiated by asserting the CS(high to low) in SPI. And then every clock based on polarity and phase the data is transmitted/sampled. My doubt is once data has been transferred and CS is asserted again(low to high), does the clock pulse still continues or clock pulse is only there till the communication is maintained. 
Please reply.

Answer (score -1):

Generally the clock pulses only when CS is pulled low.